# keep a specific ratio with a % based height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, aspect-ratio

So I was playing with aspect ratio to learn from some mistake I made before and ran into somekind of headache.

In my code the w/h ratio of my div is kept based on the height of my div (could be width but picked height) however due to the width being %, the size of my div is based on the height and width of the window it open in.

What I'd like to do is being able to keep the ratio based on height % but to not have the width distorted depending on the size of the window.

I understand that to do so I shouldn't use % based solutions, however I can't seem to find a unit or way that could do it without screwing up the div size.

Any idea on how I should proceed ?

Here is the code :http://jsfiddle.net/L9Srn/

```
<div id="container">
</div>

html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    background: red;
    width: 26.25%;
    height: 72.3%;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
}
(function( $ratio ) {
  $.fn.keepRatio = function(which) {
      var $this = $(this);
      var w = $this.width();
      var h = $this.height();
      var ratio = w/h;
      $(window).resize(function() {
          switch(which) {
              case 'width':
                  var nh = $this.width() / ratio;
                  $this.css('height', nh + 'px');
                  break;
              case 'height':
                  var nw = $this.height() * ratio;
                  $this.css('width', nw + 'px');
                  break;
          }
      });

  }
})( jQuery );      

$(function(){
    $('#container').keepRatio('height');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L9Srn/4/show/

**Take a look:**http://jsfiddle.net/L9Srn/4/

```
var box= $('#container'),
    ratio= 0.363,
    height= 200;

box.height(height).width(height*ratio);
```

I think all you need to understand is that in css 100% means usually parent's dimensions. And is subjective and can change..And yet there is no way to select what that % represents.

Comment: it's not...but again i am not still sure what you were looking for...you want box to resize with browser y/n. and you want it to resize with aspect ratio.

Comment: Oh! I'd like my box to always have 72.3% height but to have a width ratio that's always the same. this way no matter the size of the window my div will always have the same aspect and will always be at the same place. something like height = this.height but % aren't selectable if I get you right so I'm not really sure on how to proceed.

Comment: ok so you want height to be based on height of lets say window in percentage...and you want width to be based ratio/% of that height. Which is same as saying width= ratio*(heightOfBox) which is same as saying width= ratio*( % of window's height ). Whereas in normal conditions % for width means % of its parent container...it's doable give me a sec.

Comment: Alright it's done.... http://jsfiddle.net/L9Srn/4/show/ try resizing the browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/L9Srn/4/

Comment: wow exactly what I was looking for. Thanks awfully for your time that helped me a lot to improve !

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS only if you wish

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/5tzk3/307/

```
.wrapper:after {
    padding-top: 100%; /*Sets ratio*/
    display: block;
    content: '';
}
```

Comment: Hello Vector, thanks for you help, however padding-top affect only width if I remember right. Which means that I can't use it in the case of height